# Проблема с доступом (открытием?) порта 3306 macOS

Tags: mysql, macos, mac

Всем привет, у меня возникла проблема с доступом к порту 3306 в macOS

Для проверки я использовал https://portscaner.ru/

У меня белый динамичный айпи адресс
[image: Инфо про айпи]
[image: Настройки]

Что я пробовал?

1. Я вводил команду `nc -l 3306` в "ответ получил сообщение" `nc: Address already in use`
2. Я удалил все файрволлы и отключил брэндмаузер
3. Рассматривал данную статью (https://br.atsit.in/ru/?p=53421) как решение проблемы, однако после ввода `sudo nano /usr/local/etc/my.cnf` открывался пустой файл
4. Mac перезагружал, ровно как и роутер
5. Пробовал открыть порт с помощью Utorrent, но он 32-ух битный и не запускается

У меня MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020); macOS 12.5